# Native reactjs - how to specify multiple import directories

Tags: reactjs

I have folder structure

```
- src
  - js
    ... more folders
  - css
    ... more folders
```

I want to avoid complicated relativity in my import statement paths. Is there a place where I say something like:

`look into not only 'src' but also in 'src/js' and 'src/css' when i try to import a file`

Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, you can't import a whole folder like that natively but you can create a `index.js` (assuming you are using NodeJS, Webpack or other bundlers that supports this feature) and specify what will be exported if you import that folder. Like this:

```
// src/js/cat/cat.js
export Cat = { name: 'Tom' };

// src/js/cat/index.js
export Cat from './cat.js';

// src/js/dog/dog.js
import { Cat } from '../cat';

export Dog = { name: 'Spot', hate: Cat };

// src/js/dog/index.js
export Dog from './dog.js';

// src/js/index.js
export Cat from './cat';
export Dog from './dog';

// src/test.js
import { Cat, Dog } from './js';
```

About CSS files, unless you are using a CSS preprocessor (SASS,...), I don't think it is possible.